# Chrome cannot use Virtual Smart Card, IE works fine

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, internet-explorer, chromium, smartcard

In Chrome under Windows 8.1, when logging in to a site that requires a certificate, and trying to use a [Virtual Smart Card](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593708.aspx), I'm getting the message "The security device cannot perform the requested operation or the operation requires a different smart card". Physical smart card works fine on Chrome, IE works fine with either virtual or physical smart card. Tried to run Chrome as administrator, no success.

[image]

Comment: Have you reported the issue to Google?

Comment: Yes. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516537